# Null pointer exception: Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference Android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a database in android and am calling the create function defined in DBManager from the onCreateInputView() in another file.

Below are the files that are needed. New to android and not too sure what is happening. What must I do? And what does this error mean?

DBManager.java

```
package com.project.pesit.finaltelim;



import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.LauncherActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DBManager extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    private final Context context;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "gredict";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE1 ="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS wordindex (wid INTEGER(4), word VARCHAR(256), gremeaning VARCHAR(1024), isFav TINYINT(1));";
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE2 ="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS lists (wid INTEGER(4), sid INTEGER(8), isDefault TINYINT(1));";
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE3 ="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS gloss (sid INTEGER(8), meaning VARCHAR(1024), pos INTEGER(1));";

    public DBManager(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context=context;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {

        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE1);
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE2);
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE3);

        BufferedReader br = null;
        String sCurrentLine;

        //Populate word index table
        try
        {
            Resources res=context.getResources();
            InputStream is = res.openRawResource(R.raw.wordindex);
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                db.execSQL(sCurrentLine);
            }

        }

        catch
                (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally
        {
            try
            {
                if (br != null)br.close();
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        //Populate lists table
        try
        {

            Resources res=context.getResources();
            InputStream is = res.openRawResource(R.raw.list);
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                db.execSQL(sCurrentLine);
            }
        }

        catch
                (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally
        {
            try
            {
                if (br != null)br.close();
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        //Populate gloss table
        try
        {
            Resources res=context.getResources();
            InputStream is = res.openRawResource(R.raw.gloss);
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                db.execSQL(sCurrentLine);
            }
        }

        catch
                (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally
        {
            try
            {
                if (br != null)br.close();
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }




    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion,
                          int newVersion)
    {

        onCreate(db);
    }


    public Boolean open() throws SQLException
    {
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return true;
    }

    public void close()
    {
        db.close();
    }


    public List<String> read(String box)
    {

        List<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>();
        String query;
        Cursor cursor=null;
        if(box.equals("HF"))
        {
            query = "SELECT distinct word FROM wordindex WHERE wid<335";
        }
        else
        {
            query = "SELECT distinct word FROM wordindex WHERE word LIKE '"+box+"%' and wid>334";
        }
        cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String word;
                word=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("word"));
                wordList.add(word);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        cursor.close();
        return wordList;
    }

    public List<String[]> getWord(String name){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //String[] cols=new String []{WORD,MEAN};
        //String sid=String.valueOf(id);
        List<String[]> meanings = new ArrayList<String[]>();

        Cursor c1=db.rawQuery("SELECT DISTINCT (sid) FROM lists WHERE wid = (SELECT wid FROM wordindex where word='"+name+"')",null);
        if (c1.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

                int sid=c1.getColumnIndex("sid");
                Cursor c2=db.rawQuery("SELECT pos, meaning FROM gloss WHERE sid = "+c1.getString(sid),null);

                if (c2.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {

                        int ipos=c2.getColumnIndex("pos");
                        int imean=c2.getColumnIndex("meaning");
                        String pos=null;
                        if(c2.getInt(ipos)==0)
                            pos="(n)";
                        else if(c2.getInt(ipos)==1)
                            pos="(v)";
                        else if(c2.getInt(ipos)==2)
                            pos="(adj)";
                        String mean[] = {pos,c2.getString(imean)};

                        meanings.add(mean);
                    } while (c2.moveToNext());
                }

            } while (c1.moveToNext());
        }


        return meanings;
    }

    public String getGREMeaning(String name){

        String meaning=null;
        Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT gremeaning FROM wordindex where word='"+name+"'",null);
        c.moveToFirst();

        int imean=c.getColumnIndex("gremeaning");
        meaning=c.getString(imean);

        return meaning;
    }

    public String getGREMeaningWID(int wid){

        String meaning=null;
        Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT gremeaning FROM wordindex where wid='"+wid+"'",null);
        c.moveToFirst();

        int imean=c.getColumnIndex("gremeaning");
        meaning=c.getString(imean);

        return meaning;
    }

    public List<ListItem> getList(String word) {
        List<ListItem> l=new ArrayList<ListItem>();
        int groupcount;
        Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM lists where wid in(SELECT wid from wordindex where word='"+word+"')",null);
        int imean=c.getColumnIndex("sid");
        for(c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext())
        {   Cursor s=db.rawQuery("SELECT distinct wid FROM lists where sid="+c.getString(imean),null);
            int index=s.getColumnIndexOrThrow("wid");
            groupcount=s.getCount();
            if(groupcount>1){
                ListItem li=new ListItem();
                li.setSID(c.getString(imean));
                for(s.moveToFirst();!s.isAfterLast();s.moveToNext())
                {
                    li.addWID(s.getString(index));

                }
                l.add(li);
            }
        }
        return l;
    }

    public List<ListItem> getGroupList() {
        List<ListItem> l=new ArrayList<ListItem>();

        Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT sid,meaning FROM v2",null);
        for(c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext())
        {
            ListItem li=new ListItem();
            li.setSID(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("sid")));
            li.setGloss(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("meaning")));
            l.add(li);
        }

        /*
        Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT sid FROM  `v` WHERE  `count` >1",null);
        int imean=c.getColumnIndex("sid");
        for(c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext())
        {
            Cursor s=db.rawQuery("SELECT sid,meaning FROM gloss where sid="+c.getString(imean),null);
            s.moveToFirst();
            ListItem li=new ListItem();
            li.setSID(s.getString(s.getColumnIndex("sid")));
            li.setGloss(s.getString(s.getColumnIndex("meaning")));
        l.add(li);
        }
        */
        return l;
    }

    public String getGloss(String sid)
    {
        Cursor c=db.rawQuery("select meaning from gloss where sid="+sid,null);
        int i=c.getColumnIndex("meaning");
        if(c.moveToFirst())
        {
            return c.getString(i);
        }
        return "null";
    }
    public String getwd(String wid)
    {
        Cursor c=db.rawQuery("select word from wordindex where wid="+wid,null);
        int i=c.getColumnIndex("word");
        if(c.moveToFirst())
        {
            return c.getString(i);
        }
        return "null";
    }

    public List<String> getGroupWords(String sid)
    {
        List<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>();
        String query;
        Cursor cursor=null;
        query = "SELECT wid,isDefault FROM lists WHERE sid="+sid;
        cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        int iwid=cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("wid");
        int defid=cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("isDefault");
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT word FROM wordindex WHERE wid="+cursor.getString(iwid),null);
                c.moveToFirst();
                String word;
                word=c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("word"));

                wordList.add(word+":"+cursor.getString(defid));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        cursor.close();
        return wordList;
    }

    public String addToGroup(String sid, String word)
    {
        String wid=null;
        Cursor cursor=null;
        String query = "SELECT wid FROM wordindex WHERE word='"+word+"'";
        cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        String result=null;
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            wid=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("wid"));

            cursor.close();

            query = "SELECT * FROM lists WHERE wid="+wid+" AND sid="+sid;
            cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
            if(cursor.moveToFirst())
            {
                result="Word already in the group.";
            }
            else
            {
                query = "INSERT INTO lists VALUES("+wid+", "+sid+",0);";
                try{
                    db.execSQL(query);
                    result="Added successfully";
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    result="Could not add the word.";
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public String newGroup(String meaning, String pos, String word)
    {
        if(pos.equals("Noun"))
            pos="0";
        else if(pos.equals("Verb"))
            pos="1";
        else if(pos.equals("Adjective"))
            pos="2";

        String wid;
        int max;
        String query = "SELECT max(sid) FROM lists;";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        String result=null;
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        max=Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("max(sid)")));
        cursor.close();

        query = "SELECT wid FROM wordindex WHERE word='"+word+"'";
        cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        wid=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("wid"));
        cursor.close();

        try{
            query = "INSERT INTO lists VALUES ("+wid+", "+(max+1)+",0);";
            db.execSQL(query);
            query = "INSERT INTO gloss VALUES ("+(max+1)+", '"+meaning+"',"+pos+");";
            db.execSQL(query);

            db.execSQL("DROP VIEW v1;");
            db.execSQL("CREATE  VIEW v1 AS SELECT sid, isDefault, COUNT(sid) as count FROM lists GROUP BY sid;");
            db.execSQL("DROP VIEW v2;");
            db.execSQL("CREATE  VIEW v2 AS SELECT sid,meaning FROM gloss where sid IN (SELECT sid FROM v1 WHERE count>1);");

            result="Created successfully";
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            result="Could not create group.";
        }

        return result;
    }

    public List<String> search(String text,String box)
    {

        List<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>();
        String query;
        Cursor cursor=null;
        if(box.equals("HF"))
        {
            query = "SELECT distinct word FROM wordindex WHERE wid<335 and word LIKE '"+text+"%'";
        }
        else
        {
            query = "SELECT distinct word FROM wordindex WHERE word LIKE '"+box+"%' and wid>334 and word LIKE'"+text+"%'";
        }
        cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String word;
                word=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("word"));
                // Adding word to list
                //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), word, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                wordList.add(word);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        cursor.close();
        return wordList;
    }
    public List<ListItem> searchGroup(String text)
    {
        List<ListItem> l=new ArrayList<ListItem>();
        //List<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>();
        String query;
        Cursor c=null;
        query = "SELECT * FROM wordindex WHERE word LIKE'"+text+"%'";

        c = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        for(c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext())
        {
            Cursor s=db.rawQuery("SELECT sid,meaning FROM gloss where sid in(SELECT sid from lists where wid="+c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("wid"))+")",null);
            for(s.moveToFirst();!s.isAfterLast();s.moveToNext())
            {
                //s.moveToFirst();
                ListItem li=new ListItem();
                li.setSID(s.getString(s.getColumnIndex("sid")));
                li.setGloss(s.getString(s.getColumnIndex("meaning")));
                l.add(li);
            }

        }
        c.close();
        return l;
    }
    public String getID(String word1)
    {
        Cursor c=db.rawQuery("select wid from wordindex where word='"+word1+"'",null);
        int i=c.getColumnIndex("wid");
        if(c.moveToFirst())
        {
            return c.getString(i);
        }
        return "null";
    }

    public List<String> getFavList()
    {

        List<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>();
        String query;
        Cursor cursor=null;
        query = "SELECT distinct word FROM wordindex WHERE isFav=1";
        cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String word;
                word=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("word"));
                wordList.add(word);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        cursor.close();
        return wordList;
    }

    public Boolean isFav(String word)
    {
        Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT isFav FROM wordindex WHERe word='"+word+"'",null);
        int i=c.getColumnIndex("isFav");
        if(c.moveToFirst())
        {
            if(c.getString(i).equals("1"))
            {
                return true;
            }

            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void toggleFav(String word, Boolean isFav)
    {
        String fav;
        if(isFav)
        {
            fav="1";
        }

        else
        {
            fav="0";
        }
        db.execSQL("UPDATE wordindex SET isFav="+fav+" WHERE word='"+word+"'");


    }

    public int getWordCount()
    {
        Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT MAX(wid) FROM wordindex",null);
        int i=c.getColumnIndex("MAX(wid)");
        if(c.moveToFirst())
        {
            return c.getInt(i);
        }

        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    public String getBoxCount(String box)
    {

        //List<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>();
        String query;
        String query1;
        String result="";
        Cursor cursor=null;
        Cursor cursor1=null;

        if(box.equals("HF"))
        {
            return "1@334";
        }
        else
        {   query1 = "SELECT MIN(wid) AS count FROM wordindex WHERE word LIKE '"+box+"%' and wid>334";
            query = "SELECT MAX(wid) AS count FROM wordindex WHERE word LIKE '"+box+"%' and wid>334";
        }
        cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        cursor1 = db.rawQuery(query1, null);

        if (cursor1.moveToFirst()) {
            result+=cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndexOrThrow("count"));
        }
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            result+="@"+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("count"));
        }

        cursor.close();
        return result;
    }
    public String removefromgroup(String item,String sid)
    {
        String result;
        String query;
        Log.d("ITEM",item);
        Log.d("MEANING",getGloss(sid));
        String wid=getID(item);
        query="DELETE FROM lists WHERE wid="+wid+" AND sid="+sid;
        try{
            db.execSQL(query);
            result=item+" removed successfully";
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            result="Could not delete the word.";
        }
        return result;
    }}
```

onCreateInputView.java

```
@Override public View onCreateInputView() {
        mInputView = (KeyboardView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.input, null);
        mInputView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
        mInputView.setKeyboard(mQwertyKeyboard);
        DBManager mDBAdapter = new DBManager(getApplicationContext());
        //  boolean a=mDBAdapter.checkDatabase(getApplicationContext());
        //if (!mDBAdapter.checkDatabase(getApplicationContext())) {
//              try{
//                  sampleDB=getApplicationContext().openOrCreateDatabase(DB_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
//
//              }catch(SQLiteException e){
//                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not create database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//              }sampleDB.close();


            mDBAdapter.onCreate(sampleDB);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Database Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       // }else{

           //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //}
        return mInputView;

    }
```

The error log is as follows:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
            at com.project.pesit.finaltelim.DBManager.onCreate(DBManager.java:44)
            at com.project.pesit.finaltelim.SoftKeyboard.onCreateInputView(SoftKeyboard.java:118)
            at android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService.updateInputViewShown(InputMethodService.java:1108)
            at android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService.showWindowInner(InputMethodService.java:1493)
            at android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService.showWindow(InputMethodService.java:1468)
            at android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService$InputMethodImpl.showSoftInput(InputMethodService.java:433)
            at android.inputmethodservice.IInputMethodWrapper.executeMessage(IInputMethodWrapper.java:203)
            at com.android.internal.os.HandlerCaller$MyHandler.handleMessage(HandlerCaller.java:37)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
```

Comment: can you tell me what's line 44 in DBmanger ?? Thx

Comment: db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE1); in onCreate() function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never ever call the `onCreate` method yourself, the `SQLiteOpenHelper` class will do this for you automatically.

**Remove this line from your code at onCreateInputView.java:**

```
mDBAdapter.onCreate(sampleDB);
```

Comment: Thank you. The app is running now. Still a long way to go before I achieve what I'm trying to. :)

Answer (score 1):

The argument (`db`) to `SQLiteOpenHelper.onCreate()` is `null`; that's why a `NullPointerException` is thrown.

Comment: This does clearly not answer the question as the onCreate method is normally called by an underlying API.